# If/Then/Do statement not working in SAS

Tags: sas

I have an IF/Then/Do statement that used to work but after some modification it's no longer working. I want a certain condition met and when it is met then I want it to send an email. If it isn't met then I don't want the email sent. The email portion of the code works fine, in fact, it sends the email regardless if the condition is met or not. I've tested the IF/Then/Do statement several times with data I know will meet and not meet the condition. Below is the script:

```
    data Hoth;
    IF (Luke = '1' and Darth = '0') then do;
    data _NULL_;
    filename myemail EMAIL
    to="me@lando.com"
    cc="me@lando.com"
    from="me@lando.com"
    subject="Millenium Falcon"
    importance="HIGH";
    file myemail;
    put "Han,";
    put " ";
    put "Look out for the asteroids.";
    put " ";
    put "Thank you.";
    put " ";
    put "Obi";
    run;
```

Comment: You need to review your code. you have embedded data steps. Your code would not work in the current form at all .

Comment: Reverse your modifications until it works, but as is that code would never have worked. For conditional execution you need macro %IF/%THEN and a macro.  Why two DATA statements.

Comment: I switched around a little more. For some reason the the condition would work and trigger the email but it wouldn't send the info in the body of the email without the data _NULL_ statement.

Comment: If you don't mind me saying, it is a poorly written code. Where is your "set" statement? How IF clause would ever get satisfied? "Luke" and "Darth" variables would always me initialised missing in your program.

Comment: I have the condition working fine. The problem I'm having now is that when it meets the condition it's sending an email with the body of the text. If it doesn't meet the condition then it's sending an email with blank text. Ultimately I want it to send the email with the text if it meets the condition. If it doesn't meet the condition then i don't want it to send an email at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using email directives to allow conditional control over the email that your data step is generating.

```
data Millenium_Falcon;
    han='1';
    luke='0';
    darth='0';
run;

filename myemail EMAIL
    to="me@lando.com"
    cc="me@lando.com"
    from="me@lando.com"
    subject="Millenium Falcon"
    importance="HIGH"
;

data _null_;
    set Millenium_Falcon ;
    file myemail;
    IF (Luke = '1' and Darth = '0') then do;
        put "Han,";
        put " ";
        put "Look out for the asteroids.";
        put " ";
        put "Thank you.";
        put " ";
        put "Obi";
    end;
    else do;
        put '!EM_ABORT!';
    end;
    stop;
run;
```